# Build relationship between two tables with Times that are bnot exact but close

Tags: powerbi

I have two tables that i need to build a relationship. They both have a timestamp that I want to use to match the data. The problem is that the timestamps are not exact and my be off by a few seconds,. Eg 8.32.50 and 8.32.45.  I could use the hh.mm (change date time to integer)to match the data as but the problem arise in a situation where e.g the times are 8.32.58 and 8.33.067

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to set up a *time-dimension table*. A time-dimension table goes down to the granularity of seconds, so you can relate both tables to that one dimension table so that they can "speak" to one another. Radacad has a great script for creating one [here](https://radacad.com/script-for-creating-time-table-in-power-bi-with-hours-minutes-and-seconds-buckets), which also has time-binning columns.